# Kakah krishna pikah krishna.. Where this verse comes from?

Tags: identification-request, shloka

I don't know much about Sanskrit verses/shlokas, one of my friends found this in social networking web sites and forwarded to me. Is it from any scriptures or modern authors?

I just want to know the source and meaning.. I googled it and found [this](https://www.samskrittutorial.in/classes/class_6/script/8.1.pdf)

> काकः कृष्णः पिकः कृष्णः को भेद पिककाकयोः
>
> वसन्तसमये प्राप्ते काकः काकः पिकः पिकः
>
> **Kakah krishna pikah krishna, Ko bheda pika kaka yoho?**
>
> **Vasanta samaye praptey, Kakah kakah pikah pikaha!**

Answer (score 8):

> Kaka - crow , Krishna - black
>   Pika - cuckoo , Krishna - black
>   Ko Bheda - what difference ?
>   Vasanta praptey - spring comes
>   Crow - Crow , Cuckoo - Cuckoo

Crow & Cuckoo are both black. Then what's the difference ? Come spring time, you'll know which is which (based on singing voice, cuckoo melody, crow noise).

Ordinary men and advanced saints look the same, both eat, sleep etc. So why respect one alone ? Because when it comes time to display one's knowledge and action, the difference becomes clear.

This is part of Subhashitani - or 'good sayings' - verses/proverbs taught to children learning Sanskrit.

Comment: This reminds me of the [following poem](http://prasannk.tripod.com/poems.htm) (Just read the first one **Uppu Kappurambu ...**) in Telugu written by [Vemana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vemana)

Comment: @VivekanandSV, all those verses are amazingly relevant to life.

Comment: yes, they are ... We used to have those poems in school. We didn't understand those then, but now, thankfully, we do :)